# Scrollable image stack using Blazor Component

Tags: c#, blazor

Is it possible to use C# for creating a scrollable image stack in a Blazor app, much like what you’d see in a DICOM viewer? Or is this something better suited for JavaScript? I have all of the images I want to scroll through as bitmaps, but I don’t know how to go about using a scroll event in Blazor without using JS.

Comment: Possible, yes. How many images in a stack and how large would each image be?

Comment: So if I just do a single view, say axial, a single anatomical image could be broken down into like 75 bitmaps, each representing a 2D slice out of a 3D plane. I can’t imagine the images would be more than 1MB each. Right now I am storing the images in an array of bitmaps, but I originally was storing them in a Dictionary - I figure array is faster and more memory efficient though.

Comment: You'd really struggle to have all that loaded in the browser, so I'm thinking you'd need to only hold current±1 images at any time and that would be relatively easy to manage in Blazor. I would probably look at three image elements stacked on top of each other and just manipulate the styles to flip through them with background loading of the next images.

Comment: If you are thinking of server side Blazor/razor components, things will get trickier due to the size of the images and the SignalR Comms

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be a lot and have some good downsampling algorithms, but only loading a few in at a time is a good idea too. What I’m having trouble with is how Blazor handles scroll events and how to capture that in the image div, whereas it seems to be fairly commonplace in JS. But, I’m using Blazor so I’d like to explore C# options first.

Comment: There are mouse and touch events, but I haven't tried what you need so don't know how suitable they are.

Comment: Ok, had a quick play and yes it is very easy. I'll add an answer

Comment: If you know of any publicly available image sets, I'd like to try this with some to see if we need to do something more complicated like having more images loaded at one time and loading them in the background between scrolls

Comment: https://radiopaedia.org/cases/18q-syndrome?lang=us has some good images. They’re low res case studies. You can download the images from the sidebar or within the viewer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186872/discussion-between-mister-magoo-and-normal-chemist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an extremely basic implementation of an Image Stack - you would probably need to optimise it for high res images.

```
<h1>ImageStack</h1>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">@img</div>
    <div class="row"><img src="@img" onmousewheel="@MouseWheel" /></div>
</div>

@functions
{

  int imgNumber = 0;
  string img => $"/images/explosion {imgNumber}.png";

  Task MouseWheel(UIWheelEventArgs args)
  {
      imgNumber += Math.Sign(args.DeltaY);
      if (imgNumber == 43) imgNumber = 0;
      if (imgNumber == -1) imgNumber = 42;
      return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```

DeltaY returns a positive or negative number depending on the direction of movement of the mousewheel .

I'm working with a set of 43 images named "explosion N.png" where N ranges from 0 to 42.

The img tag has a binding "onmousewheel" to the method MouseWheel which simply increments or decrements the imgNumber (and keeps it within the range 0 to 42).

The img "src" is bound to the property "img" which builds a string pointing to the image file under wwwroot.

You would need to adjust that system to whatever method of storing your image locations you require.

Comment: This is so much simpler than I was imagining it would be. I can’t tell you how grateful I am for you giving me such a giant shove in the right direction.

Comment: Blazor is awesome!

Comment: @normalchemist I just realised there is UIWheelEventArgs , which means I don't need the dynamic. One line simpler!

Comment: Not needing the dynamic keyword also means that you don’t need to reference CSharp.dll in the project assembly on .NET Core